# How to present a scene from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, appdelegate

Is it possible to present a scene from AppDelegate? My AppDelegate implements a delegate function from an ad network library and I need to present a scene when that gets called.

I tried using

```
let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(2.0)

let nextScene = SceneCoordinator.shared.gameScene
nextScene!.scaleMode = .AspectFill

GameOverScene().scene!.view?.presentScene(nextScene!, transition: transition)
```

But for some reason nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question, used -

```
 (self.window?.rootViewController!.view as! SKView).presentScene(nextScene!, transition: transition)
```